# General advice for A-level students wanting to pursue quantum physics

Tags: physics

I am a student and I will hopefully start preparation for my **A**-level examinations this June. Unlike most students in Bangladesh, I plan to build my future based on Quantum Physics and thus have not received sufficient advise on what to do.

Edexcel offers many subjects for **A**-levels but I am unsure which ones do I need.
 So far I am sure that I need:

- Chemistry (All 5 units)
- Physics (All 5 units)
- Core Mathematics (All 4 papers)
- Further Pure Mathematics (All 3 papers)
- Mechanics (All 3 papers)

Generally students take 4 subjects and ignore some units or papers but to have a good preparation for what is coming ahead, I have planned to take 5 subjects and not miss out on any unit or paper. However I am unsure whether I need statistics or not. I have understood it plays an important part in Quantum Physics (Feynman diagrams for one) but am unsure if it is really that important or not (3 more papers).

Recently, my grandfather's school friend came to visit. Despite being a geologist, he had sound knowledge of Quantum Physics (But not of the education system). He advised me to not drop Biology for my **O**-levels as it will play an important part in the 'Theory of Everything'. I did decide to appear for Biology in my **O**-levels but should I also take it for my **A**-level examinations? (5 more units)

**P.S.** Each unit requires one paper so I may have to give 28 papers (generally people give 11 papers). If you want to learn more about **A**-levels click [here](http://qualifications.pearson.com/en/qualifications/edexcel-a-levels/about.html).

This may seem like personal advice but it will actually help many more students out in the world who plan to make a career out of Quantum Physics. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the subjects required by a university that offers Quantum Physics and that you'd like to attend. Study the subjects they require.

You'll perhaps be surprised that universities don't require all the subjects you've listed. These subjects are nonetheless useful, they just aren't absolutely necessary, moreover, universities know that students have limited study time. Important aspects of subjects that you don't study will be covered at university. (Furthermore, you can study any aspects that you consider important, but aren't covered.)

Comment: Could you suggest one such university, preferably in Australia. I am quite willing to slave two years rather than fall behind later on (I am a studyholic). The subjects won't be as much of a struggle as I have studied hard for my **O**-levels and in my spare time have studied more advanced stuff. Could you edit your answer to include something on Biology as I know that no university requires it for Quantum Physics?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan You should be able to find out what universities are in Australia - and the answer given is very apt.

Comment: @SolarMike do most universities offer courses in Quantum Physics? I do not know one that offers that in Bangladesh, hence my confusion.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I don't think Bangladesh is relevant as it is not in Australia, and, in your comment you specifically ask about Australia, so you need to find out which Universities offer Quantum Mechanics in Australia - they should list the courses they offer, along with the minimum entry requirements.

Comment: @SolarMike I only specified Australia as I may be moving there for University. But the minimum entry requirements surprise me. My **O**-level knowledge is more than sufficient for most requirements and others aren't that difficult. Anyways. thanks for the help!

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan You certainly need a willingness to work, but there is only so much you can study and it might be better to focus your studies on fewer subjects, to ensure you master those, rather than spreading your efforts on more subjects, for breadth. Of course, such discussion is highly subjective.

Comment: @user2768 thank you for your advice. I'll remember that.

Comment: Regarding biology, study it at A-level only if it is needed. (You can always study subjects in your spare time too.)

Comment: Typically for physics in the UK universities ask for A levels in maths and physics, plus one other - further maths and chemistry are both good choices. I think you're fine with your plans for now. If you want to try and get ahead - taking a degree is more about learning a way of thinking than more and more facts. So I'd suggest looking at physics/math challenges and trying out the knowledge you have on random problems. You could also look at programming; computational physics is a big thing and used to tackle for many quantum physics problems.